# Can Groovy only create macros on classes and methods?

Tags: macros, groovy

It seems to me (from Groovy in Action 2nd edition) that Groovy can only manipulate ASTs for as a specific subset of possible ASTs - Classes, methods, field definitions etc. However it seems not to be possible to annotate/manipulate any other piece of code.

1. Is this observation correct?
2. Why is this so? That is why cant I annotate any expression?
3. Are there any plans to allow to annotate at least closures?

I'd like to do something like this for example

```
def some_method() {
    @with_resource(my_resource) {
         // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you can also annotate properties and script variables. Off the top of my head, `@Lazy` and `@Field` are 2 examples

Answer (score 0):

With class [ClosureExpression](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/expr/ClosureExpression.html), you can detect a closure and do whatever you want to modify it. Here is a [wrapping example](http://sysgears.com/notes/groovy-ast-put-method-code-into-a-closure/)

AST lets you modify anything in the code and allow you to construct powerful tools. Browse the [list of expressions implemented](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/expr/package-summary.html) or [nodes](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/expr/package-summary.html) and see by yourself

EDIT : As we're talking about annotations and not pure AST, here is an addendum

You can't annotate a block of code (or a closure), and that's not Groovy AST Limitation, that's Java Limitation as targets of annotations are limited to these [ElementType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html)

What you could do is something like :

```
def some_method(@with_resource(my_resource) Closure cl) {
    cl.call()
}
```

Comment: well again this takes a method as an input. I'd like to transform a closure WITHIN a method.

Comment: Would you please give an example of what you yhink you can't do. I think I don't really get your point

Comment: as you present it, I think my_resource is considered as a method call, not a closure in itself. ASTTransformation can do anything you want, but annotation are limited to what Java is limited to : Classes, method and fields, etc, so called [Element types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html)

Comment: my_resource is simply meant as the resource that should be operated on. just assume that the block given to @with_resource would open a database connection execute the given block on it and close it again and wrap everything into a try catch block